# Add time duration to date using addHours() in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, duration

I want to add time duration to my datetime variable. I am reading the duration from a csv file. The format of duration is 0:29:40 or 1:29:40. When i add this to datetime variable it gives exception of incorrect format. How can I add the duration using this format. Previously I had duration as a simple integer like "6" or "7" but now the format is this "0:29:40" I don't know how to change my code to accommodate this format.

Previously i was doing this

```
 double hours = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            DateTime newdate = finaldate.AddHours(hours);
```

`row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` reads the value from csv

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the Cell[2]?.

Comment: How did you expect `0:29:40` to be coverted to a double?

Comment: May be you should try to convert your values to be added to TimeSpan and then add it to a DateTime instance?

Comment: @Steve its 0:29:40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to use the [`TimeSpan.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`TimeSpan.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method to properly parse your string and then simply add that `TimeSpan` result to your existing date:

```
var time = TimeSpan.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
DateTime newDate = finalDate.Add(time);
```

If you need to explicitly specify what each of the values of your time represent, then the `TimeSpan.ParseExact()` method will allow you to provide a formatting string to specify this:

```
// This will assume that 1:29:40 is hours, minutes, and seconds
var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), @"h\:m\:s", null);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to parse to a double. Parse to a `TimeSpan`. Something like:

```
var source = "0:29:40";
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse(source);
```

Now `ts` is your time span. And the nice thing with `TimeSpan` is you can just add it to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime newdate = finaldate + ts;
```